# Backbone.js binding a change event to a collection inside a model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm pretty new to Backbone so excuse me if this question is a little obvious.
I am having problems with a collection inside of a model. When the collection changes it doesn't register as a change in the model (and doesn't save).

I have set up my model like so:

```
var Article = Backbone.Model.extend({

   defaults: {
       "emsID" :  $('html').attr('id')
   },

   initialize: function() { 
       this.tags = new App.Collections.Tags();
   },

   url: '/editorial_dev.php/api/1/article/persist.json'
});
```

This works fine if I update the tags collection and manually save the model:

```
this.model.tags.add({p : "a"});

this.model.save();
```

But if the model is not saved the view doesn't notice the change. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
initialize: function() { 
    this.tags = new App.Collections.Tags();
    var model = this;
    this.tags.bind("change", function() {
        model.save();
    });
},
```

Bind to the `change` event on the inner collection and just manually call `.save` on your outer model.

Comment: Nice one, thanks. Would it be possible to set off the change event by changing the collection from the main model view? Seems like it should but if I call `this.model.tags.add({p : "b"});` it doesn't fire the event.

Comment: @AdTaylor `change` only handles attribtues changing in models inside collections. You want to bind to both `change` and `add`

Comment: you're a gent! Apologies for such a foolish question. Thanks

Comment: Minor point: isn't the best practice for accessing Backbone attributes to use the get/set method, as opposed to directly accessing the attribute? In other words: `this.get("tags")` rather than `this.tags`

Comment: Minor point: I think in the example this.tags would not actually be a model attribute. It would be a property called 'tags' at the model level and at the same level as the property attribute so this.get('tags') would give you an undefined. If he had done a this.attributes.tags = ... or this.set({tags: new App.Collections.Tags()}) then your suggestion of this.get('tags') would work. In general though, when you are dealing with model attributes, you are correct that .get() and .set() are the preferred ways of doing it. :-)

Comment: The binding part can be shortened like: `this.tags.bind('change', this.save, this)`

Comment: @AdTaylor Can you show how you define Tags? Have you defined it as a Backbone collection? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

This is actually an addendum to @Raynos answer, but it's long enough that I need answer-formatting instead of comment-formatting.

1. Clearly OP wants to bind to `change` and `add` here, but other people may want to bind to `destroy` as well.  There may be other events (I'm not 100% familiar with all of them yet), so binding to `all` would cover all your bases.

   `remove` also works instead of `destroy`.  Note that both `remove` and `destroy` fire when a model is deleted--first `destroy`, then `remove`.  This propagates up to the collection and reverses order: `remove` first, then `destroy`.  E.g.

   ```
   model event      :      destroy
   model event      :      remove
   collection event :      destroy
   collection event :      remove
   ```
2. There's a gotcha with custom event handlers described in [this blog post](http://japhr.blogspot.com/2011/11/delegated-events-in-backbonejs-im-idiot.html).

   **Summary**: Model-level events should propagate up to their collection, but can be prevented if something handles the event first and calls `event.stopPropagation`.  If the event handler returns `false`, this is a jQuery shortcut for `event.stopPropagation();
   event.preventDefault();`
3. Calling `this.bind` in a model or collection refers to **Underscore.js's** bind, **NOT** jQuery/Zepto's.  What's the difference?  The biggest one I noticed is that you cannot specify multiple events in a single string with space-separation.  E.g.

   ```
   this.bind('event1 event2 ...', ...)
   ```

   This code looks for the event called `event1 event2 ...`.  In jQuery, this would bind the callback to `event1`, `event2`, ...  If you want to bind a function to multiple events, bind it to `all` or call `bind` once for each event.  There is an [issue](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/640) filed on github for this, so this one will hopefully change.  For now (11/17/2011), be wary of this.

Comment: Note, as of 0.9.0 Backbone added support for space-delimited events.  See changelog: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#changelog